# What is the difference between the AF-S 50mm f1.8G and the AF 50mm 1.8D?

Tags: lens, nikon-d5100, af-s

I am curious to know what is the difference between an AF-S and AF lens. What makes AF-S more costly than AF? Is there any difference in image quality ?

Comment: Its a silent wave motor.  Related: [Do Nikon AF-S lenses perform better than AF lenses?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/14196/13451), and [What type of lens will auto-focus on Nikon bodies without a focus motor?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/5742/13451).

Answer (score 0):

AF-S allows instant manual-focus override simply by grabbing the focus ring at any time.

G means it has no manual aperture control

You will not be able to autofocus AF 50mm 1.8D on cheaper DSLRs

Quality is nearly the same

You can find more details here:
http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/50mm-f18-g.htm
http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/5018daf.htm